# Dropbox delegate methods are not calling first time

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, dropbox, rest-client

This is i have written in viewDidLoad.

```
 if DBSession.shared().isLinked() {
        print("already linked")

        initDropboxRestClient()
    }
    else
    {
        print("connecting2")
        DBSession.shared().link(from: self)
        initDropboxRestClient()
    }
```

and function initDropboxRestClient() is written below.

```
func initDropboxRestClient() {
    dbRestClient = DBRestClient(session: DBSession.shared())
    dbRestClient.delegate = self
    dbRestClient.loadMetadata("/")
```

}

The problem is i have two view controllers for displaying dropbox file names, the first view controller is calling the delegate methods and displaying filename and folder names perfectly. But the second one isn't.

In the second view controller,
I observed that if i scroll my tableview in second view controller up and down then the delegate methods get called immediately and once it is linked next time the methods are called immediately.

So for the first time delegate methods are not getting called in my second dropbox view controller thats my problem here. Thanks in advance.

The restClient delegate methods are as follows.

```
func restClient(_ client: DBRestClient!, loadedMetadata metadata: DBMetadata!) {
    for file in metadata.contents
    {
        dbMetadataArray.append(file as! DBMetadata)
        fileNamesArray.append((file as AnyObject).filename)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    self.myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

}

func restClient(_ client: DBRestClient!, loadMetadataFailedWithError error: Error!) {
    print("in loadMetadataFailedWithError method in dropbox email view controller")
    print("Error dscription = %@",[error.localizedDescription])
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Go Back.", message: "Try Once Again", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    self.myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant delegates methods implementation... thanks!

Comment: I have added delegate methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that might cause your delegate methods to not be called:

1. Your rest client is nil or is being released (e.g., by ARC) prematurely.
2. You're making the call in a background thread that doesn't have a run loop.
3. Your delegate method that should be called back has a typo in it. Unfortunately the SDK doesn't warn you if it can't find a delegate method to call; it just completes without telling anyone.

Also, note that the SDK you're using uses API v1, which is deprecated and being retired soon anyway:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/

You should switch to API v2:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation

Comment: Great answer ;) I would only add a 4th point: *he may be forgetting to call `tableView.reloadData()` inside his delegate* (when receiving new data from DropBox). This call would force a *refresh* in the corresponding `tableView`.

Comment: I have added delegate methods. and reload call is there.

Comment: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)

At first time i am getting the this line in my log.